# Lost Apple ID: How to recover iTunes media and iCloud data?

Tags: itunes, icloud, contacts, apple-id

I have an iPad containing all my music and iCloud data (contacts) but I lost access to my Apple ID. I want to make a backup of the data on my iPad, create a new Apple ID and then re-import the data.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just sync it with iTunes (which would also backup the contacts on the computer) on OS X or Windows. Then setup your new Apple ID, add it to the iCloud settings and continue with iCloud backup (and iTunes backup too, if you wish).

Comment: I ended up using Xilisoft's software, but this works too.